# Adding CIDR rules to PIX

Tags: pix

I have a Cisco PIX-515, version 6.3(4). I need to add a rule allowing the delivery of email from a series of IP addresses (e.g. XX.XXX.XXX.0/20). Is there a way to put such a rule into the PIX without individually entering each IP address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I think the correct answer to this question is to buy an ASA. :)

Comment: Just how would the asa be different then a PIX with regards to this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
object-group network My-LAN
 network-object 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
!
access-list My-ACL extended permit tcp any object-group My-LAN eq smtp
!
access-group My-ACL in interface My-Interfacename
!
```

you dont need to add this, i just want to share how to add the "interfacename":

```
interface Ethernet0.90
 vlan 90
 nameif My-Interfacename
 security-level 60
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
```